# How do I get an Array of recursive parent Ids from a category tree?

Tags: javascript, recursion, tree

I have the following date structure (Recursive Tree of Categories that can have 0..n subCategories)

```js
let categoryTree = [
  {
    id: 1,
    subCategories: [
      {
        id: 2,
        subCategories: [
          {
            id: 3,
            subCategories: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 4,
        subCategories: [
          {
            id: 5,
            subCategories: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    subCategories: [
      {
        id: 7,
        subCategories: [
          {
            id: 8,
            subCategories: [],
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        id: 9,
        subCategories: [
          {
            id: 10,
            subCategories: [],
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

What is the easiest way for a function which returns me an array of all recursive parent ids?

Examples:

```js
getParentIds(3) // Should return [1,2]
getParentIds(8) // Should return [6,7]
getParentIds(4) // Should return [1]
getParentIds(1) // Should return []
```

My attempt at this, however, this only works sometimes and not for all of the possible ids.

```js
function recursiveFindParent(id, categories) {

    for(let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++){
        const c = categories[i];

    const subCat = c.subCategories.find(s => s.id === id);
    
    if (subCat !== undefined) {
      return c;
    } else {
      return recursiveFindParent(id, c.subCategories);
    }
  }

}

function getParentIds(id) {
  let foundParents = [];

  let parentId = id;
  let parent = null;

  while (parent = recursiveFindParent(parentId, categories)) {
    foundParents.push(parent.id);
    parentId = parent.id;
  }

  return foundParents;
}

console.log(getParentIds(3, categoryTree));
```

Comment: For the IDs it doesn't work for, what is the *first* line that doesn't do what you expected?

Comment: I think this is solved easier by keeping track of the path to the current node as you search; as soon as you find the node you want, that path will be the list of parents you seek.

Answer (score 4):

This question comes up a lot and I recently answered it in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72407688/633183). Your specific inquiry differs enough that I'll make a new post here, however much of the work is taken directly from the original answer.

**generic find**

Recursion is a functional heritage and so by using functional style we yield the best results. By decomposing the problem, we isolate concerns and make it easier for us to write individual solutions to the smaller sub-problems.

We start with higher-order `find(t, func)` that searches `t` using function, `func`, and returns *all* paths to the matched nodes.

1. If `t` is an array, for all `child` of `t` recur on the sub-problem `find(child, func)`
2. (inductive) `t` is not an array. If `t` is an object, then if the user-supplied function returns true for `f`, yield the singleton output, `[t]`, otherwise for each `path` of the sub-problem `find(t.subCategories, func)`, prepend `t` to the `path` and yield.
3. (inductive) `t` is neither an array nor an object. Stop iteration.

```js
// node : { id: int, subCategories: node array }

// find : (node ∪ node array, node -> boolean) -> (node array) generator
function* find(t, func) {
  switch (true) {
    case is(t, Array):               // 1
      for (const child of t)
        yield* find(child, func)
      break
    case is(t, Object):              // 2
      if (Boolean(func(t)))
        yield [t]
      else for (const path of find(t.subCategories, func))
        yield [t, ...path]
      break
    default:                         // 3
      return
  }
}
```

Which depends on `is` -

```js
// is : (any, any) -> boolean
function is(t, T) { 
  return t?.constructor === T
}
```

**specialized find**

Writing `findById` is a matter of specializing `find`. We assume `id` are unique and so `return` the path to the *first* matched node, if any. Otherwise return the empty path, `[]`.

```js
// findById : (node ∪ node array, number) -> node array
function findById(t, id) {
  for (const path of find(t, node => node.id === id))
    return path
  return []
}
```

**checkpoint 1**

To demonstrate proper behavior, I wrote a `demo` function which selects only the node `id` field and creates a `->`-separated path. This allows us to us to easily confirm the output -

```js
function demo(t, id) {
  console.log(
    `== id: ${id} ==`,
    findById(data, id).map(p => p.id).join("->")
  )
}
```

```js
demo(data, 3)
demo(data, 8)
demo(data, 4)
demo(data, 1)
```

```
== id: 3 == 1->2->3
== id: 8 == 6->7->8
== id: 4 == 1->4
== id: 1 == 1
```

**only the node ancestry**

Your question asks specifically for the node's *ancestry*, which we can compute using another specialization. As we saw above, `findById` gets us all the way to the matched node. To select only its ancestry, we can simply `slice` the matched path, returning all but the last path element.

```js
// findAncestryById : (node ∪ node array, int) -> node array
function findAncestryById(t, id) {
  return findById(t, id).slice(0, -1) // ✅ all but the last
}
```

**demo**

This time we will write `demo` to perform a query using `findAncestryById` -

```js
function demo(t, id) {
  console.log(
    `== id: ${id} ==`,
    JSON.stringify(findAncestryById(data, id).map(p => p.id))
  )
}
```

```js
demo(data, 3)
demo(data, 8)
demo(data, 4)
demo(data, 1)
```

```
== id: 3 == [1,2]
== id: 8 == [6,7]
== id: 4 == [1]
== id: 1 == []
```

You can verify the output below -

```js
function is(t, T) { 
  return t?.constructor === T
}

function* find(t, func) {
  switch (true) {
    case is(t, Array):
      for (const child of t)
        yield* find(child, func)
      break
    case is(t, Object):
      if (Boolean(func(t)))
        yield [t]
      else
        for (const path of find(t.subCategories, func))
          yield [t, ...path]
      break
    default:
      return
  }
}

function findById(t, id) {
  for (const path of find(t, node => node.id === id))
    return path
  return []
}

function findAncestryById(t, id) {
  return findById(t, id).slice(0, -1)
}

function demo(t, id) {
  console.log(
    `== id: ${id} ==`,
    JSON.stringify(findAncestryById(data, id).map(p => p.id))
  )
}

const data = [{id:1,subCategories:[{id:2,subCategories:[{id:3,subCategories:[]}]},{id:4,subCategories:[{id:5,subCategories:[]}]}]},{id:6,subCategories:[{id:7,subCategories:[{id:8,subCategories:[]}]},{id:9,subCategories:[{id:10,subCategories:[]}]}]}];

demo(data, 3)
demo(data, 8)
demo(data, 4)
demo(data, 1)
```

**gotcha**

Did you notice `findAncestryById(data, 1)` returns an empty ancestry `[]`? How would the output vary if `1` could not be found in the tree? This differs from the `findById` function which returns a valid empty path `[]` when a node is not found.

The reason `findAncestryById` needs a distinction is because `[]` is the same as `[].slice(0, -1)`. For this particular function, you may want to return `null` if the node is not present in the tree. This is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: We meet again.  Amazing timing!

Comment: Hah, I always meet you @ScottSauyet

Answer (score 3):

We can see this as a variant of [a Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72407644) from a few days ago.  I leave the explanation out, as that one covers it just fine.  The only tweaks I had to make is to note the child node is called `subCategories` and to pull the `id` out of the returned list of nodes.

```js
function * walk (xs, path = []) {
  for (let x of xs) {
    const newPath = path .concat (x)
    yield newPath
    yield * walk (x .subCategories || [], newPath)
  }
}

const ancestry = (pred) =>  (obj) => {
  for (let nodes of walk (obj)) {
    if (pred (nodes .at (-1))) {
      return nodes
    }
  }
  return []
}

const findAncestryById = (tree, targetId) => 
  ancestry (({id}) => id == targetId) (tree) .map (x => x .id) .slice (0, -1)

const categoryTree = [{id: 1, subCategories: [{id: 2, subCategories: [{id: 3, subCategories: []}]}, {id: 4, subCategories: [{id: 5, subCategories: []}]}]}, {id: 6, subCategories: [{id: 7, subCategories: [{id: 8, subCategories: []}]}, {id: 9, subCategories: [{id: 10, subCategories: []}]}]}];

[3, 8, 4, 1, 42] .forEach (
  (n) => console .log (`findAncestryById (${n}) //=> [${findAncestryById (categoryTree, n)}]`)
)
```

---

Also, please look at Mulan's [excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72407688) to that same question, which works quite differently.

Comment: déjà vu! one thing i noticed this time around is that `findAncestryById` should perhaps return `null` if the node cannot be found. details in my answer

Comment: I agree it's possible, but I will also leave it as an exercise.  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

My preference is always to write readable and maintainable code (e.g. what if your data structure changes and you have `subC` and `subCategories` in your tree?). So if you are ok using a library, this might be a good answer.

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

```html
<script type="module">
import objectScan from 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/object-scan@18.2.0/lib/index.min.js';

const categoryTree = [
  { id: 1, subCategories: [{ id: 2, subCategories: [{ id: 3, subCategories: [] }] }, { id: 4, subCategories: [{ id: 5, subCategories: [] }] }] },
  { id: 6, subCategories: [{ id: 7, subCategories: [{ id: 8, subCategories: [] }] }, { id: 9, subCategories: [{ id: 10, subCategories: [] }] }] }
];

const getParentIds = objectScan(
  ['[*].**{subCategories[*]}'],
  {
    abort: true,
    filterFn: ({ value, context }) => value?.id === context,
    rtn: 'parents',
    afterFn: ({ result }) => result
      .map((p) => p?.id)
      .filter((p) => p)
      .reverse()
  }
);

console.log(getParentIds(categoryTree, 3));
// => [ 1, 2 ]
console.log(getParentIds(categoryTree, 8));
// => [ 6, 7 ]
console.log(getParentIds(categoryTree, 4));
// => [ 1 ]
console.log(getParentIds(categoryTree, 1));
// => []
</script>
```

*Disclaimer*: I'm the author of [object-scan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/object-scan)